# Is there a public domain floorplan of the Beis Hamikdash

Tags: sources-mekorot

Is there a public domain floorplan of the Beis Hamikdash?

I'm looking for something like

[image]

Comment: A you tube video is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XljGbi5PD_g

Comment: @sabbahillel is it 1. Public Domain and 2. a floorplan?

Comment: Aren't the You Tube videos public domain? It appears to be a 3-D tour of the Bais Hamikdash rather than a pictured floor plan. I realize that it does not exactly answer the question, which is why I pointed to it as a comment.

Comment: @sabbahillel ummm, no. YouTube videos are not public domain. Not at all.

Comment: OK thanks. I was not aware of that. Shows how often I look at You Tube (:-)

Comment: Everything Wiki does is CC-BY-SA - is that good enough? (It's free for reuse, commercial use, and modification as long as you provide attribution and relicense under a similar license). They have a diagram of [bayit sheni](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9)

Comment: @Bachrach44 it's at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bet_hamildash_niuton.jpg also, which page shows it's actually in the PD, not by-sa.

Comment: @Bachrach44 they only have Isaac Newton's floor plan :(

Comment: Isaac Newton apparently [drew a diagram of the Bayit rishon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bet_hamildash_niuton.jpg). It's clearly public domain but I can't vouch for it's accuracy vis-a-vis either the Talmud or modern archaeology, and from your example I assume you're looking for a picture of Bayit Sheni.

Comment: @msh210 +Shmuel - there are two separate things on wiki. The [page](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9) has a diagram at the bottom which would be CC-BY-SA since it's a unique creation by a wikipedian. The [Isaac Newton image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bet_hamildash_niuton.jpg) is PD but is a separate image - it's not what I was referring to in the first comment.

Comment: @Bachrach44 didn't notice that one :). I guess I'll just have to take a screenshot :)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin you can download it at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Temple_sketch2.png