# The kotel and the Beis HaMikdosh now

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash, geography, kotel-western-wall

There [are](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64761/27180) some floorplans of the inside of the Beis HaMikdosh, for example in the first edition of the ArtScroll gemara Yoma. However, I am looking for a (sefer) picture that describes the exact location of where the Beis HaMikdosh stood, in relation to where the kotel is now.

See image from Google Maps:

[image]

The image shows (yellow drawn area) where the kotel is. In the middle of the picture, it shows the location of where the dome of rock stands. However, are there sources/images/seforim that describe, according to the overview above, where the exact location of the Beis HaMikdosh was, including all locations like, where did the Kodesh HaKodashim stood in relation to the kotel?

On the website of the Orthodox Union, they [present](https://www.ou.org/holidays/sukkot_and_the_dedication_of_the_beit_ha_mikdash/) a modern-day image of the kotel, and behind it, you can see the location of the אולם - Ulam (entrance).

[image]

Is this image, presented by the OU a reliable image?

See also [this](https://www.beishamikdashtopics.com/2012/) picture, where you can clearly see the modern day Kotel.

[image]

I've read the possible theories. Norma Robertson presented that if you look through the gates (although not everything exists nowadays) leading heading modern-day Derech HaOfel/HaMish'ol HaAharon, you would look directly heading the Kodesh HaKodashim. This is the same location as where Zechariya's tomb is

Comment: Iirc there are a few different opinions as to the location and orientation of the building.

Comment: First of all the gold thing isn’t the Al Aqsa mosque, it’s the Dome of the Rock. Second, I know at least the popular opinion is that the Even HaShatiach aka the Kodesh HaKedoshim is right underneath the dome

Comment: http://templemountlocation.com/aerialView.html http://www.templemount.org/theories.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tuvia_Sagiv,_Temple_Mount_in_Jerusalem_with_the_Hadrian_temple_of_Jupiter_in_Baalbek_in_Lebanon_overlaid.jpg https://twitter.com/myfavenews/status/1378244981937295362

Comment: Isn't the Temple in the picture oriented the wrong way round? The entrance to the Sanctuary faced east, towards Har HaZeitim

Comment: https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/reviews/the-temple-mount/

Comment: @rosends Kaufman's theory seems pretty accurate if you ask me.

Comment: I've read the possible theories. Norma Robertson presented that if you look through the gates (although not everything exists nowadays) leading heading modern-day Derech HaOfel/HaMish'ol HaAharon, you would look directly heading the Kodesh HaKodashim. This is the same location as where Zechariya's tomb is.